# Integrating Flutter Module into Native App

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-module

I’m sorry this will be a long question. I need advice from you guys. Currently, I’m working on integrating the Flutter module into iOS App. But,  before explaining the main problem, I will describe the current situation. So, now we have one native app in A repository. Then, we have one flutter module that has a different repository (Let’s say B repository).

As documentation of the Flutter Module, it’s very easy to integrate the Flutter Module into the Native app, because from the example in the documentation the Flutter Module and Native App are in the same directory, so for installing the flutter module in the native app which can use local path cocoapods. I guess I can build xcframework from the flutter module and upload it into a release like a GitHub release, but currently, we use bitbucket which does not have a release like GitHub. And also if I upload the xcframework, it will take a lot of storage because of xcframework size. (Almost 600Mb for FlutterEngine.xcframework)

My problem is, that our native app is in a different repository with the flutter module. So, I don’t know how to integrate the flutter module if not in the same repository. Can you guys, give me some advice on how to handle this problem? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Make the flutter module and native app work in the same repository first?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is an official and documented working solution, but the author does not want to apply it.

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules ?